# Por que a MainActivity herda de ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Eu estou criando um projeto novo e minha `Activity` aparece como `ActionBarActivity:`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

alguém sabe por que ou como arrumar?

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade, não há nenhum problema em herdar da classe [`ActionBarActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html). A `ActionBarActivity` é uma superclasse incluída na biblioteca de suporte v7 ([android-support-v7-appcompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/package-summary.html)).

Usando essa biblioteca, seu app terá acesso a muitas funcionalidades (O `ActionBar` por exemplo, surgiu no Android 11) que não estão inclusas no SDK padrão em certos níveis.

Se seu app tem SDK mínimo de 11, ou não precisa usar o `ActionBar`, então poderá trocar por `Activity` sem problemas.

Resumindo: Herdar `ActionBarActivity` não causa nenhum problema, só agrega mais funcionalidades a sua `Activity`. Se está tendo problemas no uso, isso é, o compilador não acha a Classe, então precisa importar a library, como não sei sua IDE, recomendo olhar esse [support-library-setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

Se tiver outro problema, sugiro postar o erro que gera.